# does Xamarin.Forms Style support variable/parameter from applied target?

Tags: xamarin.forms, parameters, styles

I have a complicated `visual state` and don't like to copy it to everywhere, so putting it in the `ResourceDictionary`

but some `setter`'s value should be replaced by the real value from the target:

for example: the `{Parameter1}` and `{Parameter1}` are things I hope to replace.

```
<ResourceDictionary>                
            <Style x:Key="ToggleButton" TargetType="button:SfButton">
                <Setter Property="ShowIcon" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                    <VisualStateGroupList x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="ImageSource" Value="{mb:ImageAsset Source={Parameter1} }" />
                                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#3900" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="ImageSource" Value="{mb:ImageAsset Source={Parameter2} }" />
                                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#6090" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateGroupList>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
```

but in the control's instantiation there's no way to pass these arguments:

```
 <button:SfButton Style="{StaticResource ToggleButton, ??Parameter1=xxx?? }" Text="xx"/>
```

so is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: From what I understand based on the change in the state you want to change the source of the image which is cool If that is the case and you have different selected and unselected image shouldn't you be assigning it respectively where you need? Or am I misunderstanding your situation please shed some light!

Comment: @FreakyAli, yes,the final result is as what you've said,but i want a better solution.  I want to create multiple buttons with the same sytle(color/font/size for different visual state) but with its own image source, but the image source property is too deep in the sytle, if I override it in the button instantiation, I have to copy almost all of the style code everywhere, so I'm wondering if there's simple way for making this.